# Undefining functions using preprocessor macros

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I've a log system written in C++ with this type of functions to write on it:

```
    void processMessages();
    void DEBUG_MSG(const std::string& appender,const char* msg, ...);
    void INFO_MSG(const std::string& appender,const char* msg, ...);
    void WARNING_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...);
    void ERROR_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...);
    void FATAL_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...);
```

I want to disable via macros in C++. 
I've read this thread: [Disable functions using MACROS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7711704/444423) but

```
#ifdef GLOG_SILENCE
        #define processMessages     (void)sizeof
        #define DEBUG_MSG           (void)sizeof
        #define INFO_MSG            (void)sizeof
        #define WARNING_MSG         (void)sizeof
        #define ERROR_MSG           (void)sizeof
        #define FATAL_MSG           (void)sizeof
#else //GLOG_SILENCE
        void processMessages();
        void DEBUG_MSG(const std::string& appender,const char* msg, ...);
        void INFO_MSG(const std::string& appender,const char* msg, ...);
        void WARNING_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...);
        void ERROR_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...);
        void FATAL_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...);
#endif //GLOG_SILENCE
```

doesn't work properly. I keep getting errors like:

> In file included from ../src/test_core.cpp:2:
>
> ```
> ../src/test_Log.h: In member function ‘virtual void LogTestFixtureTest_defining_SILENCE_macro_avoids_write_and_processing_activity_from_log_Test::TestBody()’:
> ../src/test_Log.h:63: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
> ../src/test_Log.h:63: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
> ../src/test_Log.h:63: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘sizeof’
> ../src/test_Log.h:64: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
> ../src/test_Log.h:64: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
> ../src/test_Log.h:64: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘sizeof’
> ```

I suspect that the problem is related with the fact that Log is a class, but I don't know how to do it. 
Some help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, if these are member functions, then the "silent" versions will expand to nonsense:

```
log.(void)sizeof(stuff);
```

You could define a member function that does nothing, and macros that swallow their arguments:

```
void nothing() {}

#define processMessages(...) nothing()
```

then using the "silent" versions will give valid code that should compile away to nothing:

```
log.nothing();
```

The disadvantages of this are (a) you're relying on the compiler to inline the empty function, and not generate a function call; (b) the arguments' syntax is not checked when compiling in silent mode.

Comment: @Killrazor: If you enable optimisations, then the function will be inlined, and calling it will generate no code. If your compiler can't inline trivial functions, then you really need to get a new one.

Comment: Ohhhh, you are totally right. I haven't thought in optimization option. My compiler is perfectly able to optimize the code. Maybe my brain need an update :). Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler support [variadic macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro) you can simply define macros with empty replacements:

```
#ifdef GLOG_SILENCE
        #define processMessages(_1, _2, ...)
        #define DEBUG_MSG(_1, _2, ...)
        #define INFO_MSG(_1, _2, ...)
        #define WARNING_MSG(_1, _2, ...)
        #define ERROR_MSG(_1, _2, ...)
        #define FATAL_MSG(_1, _2, ...)
#else //GLOG_SILENCE
        void processMessages();
        void DEBUG_MSG(const std::string& appender,const char* msg, ...);
        void INFO_MSG(const std::string& appender,const char* msg, ...);
        void WARNING_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...);
        void ERROR_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...);
        void FATAL_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...);
#endif //GLOG_SILENCE
```

However, this will only work if the functions are **NOT** members of a class or a namespace, but true global functions.

Comment: If they were global functions then the code in the question would work, with the advantage that the arguments' syntax would be checked even in "silent" mode.

Comment: Indeed. As I stated in the message, glog is a class

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to work in a different way. Just declare the interface ILogger after that implement it in the different loggers, like

```
class ILogger{
 public:
        virtual void DEBUG_MSG(const std::string& appender,const char* msg, ...);
        virtual  void INFO_MSG(const std::string& appender,const char* msg, ...);
        virtual  void WARNING_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...);
        virtual  void ERROR_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...);
        virtual  void FATAL_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...);
        virtual ~ILogger(){}
};
```

For the file logger

```
class FileLogger : public ILogger{
 public:
        void DEBUG_MSG(const std::string& appender,const char* msg, ...){....}
        void INFO_MSG(const std::string& appender,const char* msg, ...){....}
        void WARNING_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...){....}
        void ERROR_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...){....}
        void FATAL_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...){....}
        virtual ~EmptyLogger(){}
};

and the empty logger like:
```

for the empty logger

```
class EmptyLogger : public ILogger{
 public:
        void DEBUG_MSG(const std::string& appender,const char* msg, ...){do nothing here}
        void INFO_MSG(const std::string& appender,const char* msg, ...){do nothing here}
        void WARNING_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...){do nothing here}
        void ERROR_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...){do nothing here}
        void FATAL_MSG(const std::string& appender, const char* msg, ...){do nothing here}
        virtual ~FileLogger(){}
};
```

after that in the place where you create the logger could be a factory make a macros in order to generate a different type of logger.

```
class LoggerFactory{
public:
 static ILogger* getLogger(/*loggertype as argument*/){
   #ifdef GLOG_SILENCE
    /* create a normal logger*/
   #else
     return new EmptyLogger();
   #endif
 }
};
```

Comment: Seems pretty good but this is not the way my Log system works. In fact, listener are already an interface but implementation are created outside the system to improve extensibility. Also, DEBUG_MSG (and the other) put messages into different queues, that accepts suscriptions of the listeners (improving flexibility).