# Zero as a function name

Tags: c++, function, visual-c++, compiler-construction

The following example compiles (VS2010 C++ compiler issues a warning C4353 though) and expression (*) evaluates to `0`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   0(1, "test"); // (*) - any number and type of arguments allowed       
   int n = 0(1, "test"); // 0
   std::string str(0(1, "test")); // Debug assertion fails - 0 pointer passed
}
```

**Is using `0` as a function name allowed/regulated by C++ standard or its resolution is compiler-specific?** I was looking in the N3242 draft but could not find anything related to this. Microsoft compiler obviously resolves such construct (or one with `__noop`) as an integer with value `0`.

warning C4353:

> warning C4353: nonstandard extension used: constant 0 as function
>   expression.  Use __noop function intrinsic instead

Comment: I would've thought this should not compile, function names cannot begin with numbers

Comment: It's probably some dumb MSVC thing that has a specific, obfuscated purpose. It doesn't compile in GCC (as seen from the warning).

Comment: Um... which part of "nonstandard extension used" made you believe the construct might be allowed by the standard?

Comment: @n.m. Huh, I overlooked that obvious hint. Thanks!

Comment: @chris : Let me see... gcc adds a non standard extension (e.g. `__attributes__`) and it is a good thing. MSVC adds its own, and it is **dumb**? Is there a logic in asserting something you know nothing about must therefore be **dumb**?

Comment: Still, that doesn't mean it's used as a function. It reminds me of constructs like `12[i]`, so it could be that the compiler does something obscure, based on some kind of `operator()` overloading?

Comment: @MrLister I was in the similar doubt and wasn't sure how to name that *zero* - a function name? an address? or just a 'construct'...as didn't know how does compiler translates/understands such 'construct'.

Comment: @MrLister: `0` is an `int`. Operator overloading has to be for used-defined types, not built-in types like `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function name is an identifier and an identifier needs to start with a non-digit (§2.11):

```
identifier:
    identifier-nondigit
    identifier identifier-nondigit
    identifier digit
```

Comment: This explains everything. Thanks!

Comment: A function name is an identifier sure, but the part that comes before the opening parenthesis in a function call doesn't have to be an identifier. For example `my_functions[0]()` is a perfectly legal function call. So is `( ( int(*)() ) 0) ()`. So if there were an implicit conversion from `int` to `int(*)()`, `0()` would be perfectly valid as well (except that it would dereference a null pointer and thus invoke UB - but it would compile is my point).

Comment: @sepp2k: Yes, other ways of referring to functions are allowed, but the specific question was: "Is using 0 as a function name allowed...", and the answer to that is clearly "no".

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm not disagreeing with the "no", I'm disagreeing with the "because it's not a valid function name".

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the answer, but I believe we can find it by a little googling...

Looking at the MSDN, I found two links:

- C4353 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a68558f.aspx
- `__noop` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6btaxcs.aspx

The second link explains the `__noop`

> The __noop intrinsic specifies that a function should be ignored and the argument list be parsed but no code be generated for the arguments. It is intended for use in global debug functions that take a variable number of arguments.

Th example shows the `__noop` can be very interesting indeed for debug code:

```
#if DEBUG
    #define PRINT printf_s
#else
    #define PRINT __noop
#endif

int main() { PRINT("\nhello\n"); }
```

Another comment on the same page gives an historical hint on the `0` function:

> The compiler converts the __noop intrinsic to 0 at compile time.

I guess that, once upon a time, this extension was called `0`, not `__noop`, and that later, Microsoft created the `__noop` keyword because it was easier to search for, more readable, less "strange" than this `0` thing, and clearly marked as an extension (because of the two leading underscores, like MSVC's `__declspec` or gcc's `__attribute__`).

### Conclusion: What about `0`?

- This is an extension (as per the warning message)
- This is an historical, deprecated extension
- Its use is deprecated in favor of `__noop`
- It was deprecated at least at the VC++2003 time (if not before)

Comment: +1 The background of this questions is actually my little study on disabling/undefining functions, inspired by question that appeared here earlier today (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226151/undefining-functions-using-preprocessor-macros). I was experimenting with #define-ing function as 0, __noop and leaving token unspecified (in which case the list of arguments within brackets would be compiled as comma operator expression and yield the last argument as the expression value).